# Rapidminer split a column without split pattern?

Tags: split, cells, rapidminer

I have a table, which includes in one column the values ANNI and in other lines ANNI 2343355.

I want to split the cells which includes ANNI 2343355.

That's what I have:

[image: ATM]

And this is what I want:

[image: Goal]

Actually the answers helped me a lot, but now I have another Problem.
[that's my process now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXJaT.jpg)

But the result looks like that:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEt42.jpg)

I don't know where I messed up your code, but I would be very thankful if u could help me another time.

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: I tried the Split-Operator as well as I tried the Trim Operator, but due to the fact that I didn't work that long with rapid miner until now, may I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the *Split* operator to separate a string value based on a regex pattern. In your example, a simple `\s` for a whitespace character is sufficient.  Afterwards you need to do some post-processing do get everything in the desired format. See the example below. You can just copy&paste the XML snippet in your RapidMiner process window.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><process version="9.0.000-BETA">
<context>
<input/>
<output/>
<macros/>
</context>
<operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="9.0.000-BETA" expanded="true" name="Process">
<process expanded="true">
  <operator activated="true" class="subprocess" compatibility="9.0.000-BETA" expanded="true" height="82" name="Subprocess" width="90" x="112" y="34">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="9.0.000-BETA" expanded="true" height="68" name="Generate Data by User Specification" width="90" x="45" y="34">
        <list key="attribute_values">
          <parameter key="Name" value="&quot;ANNI 12345&quot;"/>
          <parameter key="Number" value="67890"/>
        </list>
        <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="generate_data_user_specification" compatibility="9.0.000-BETA" expanded="true" height="68" name="Generate Data by User Specification (2)" width="90" x="45" y="136">
        <list key="attribute_values">
          <parameter key="Name" value="&quot;ANNI&quot;"/>
          <parameter key="Number" value="67890"/>
        </list>
        <list key="set_additional_roles"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="append" compatibility="9.0.000-BETA" expanded="true" height="103" name="Append" width="90" x="246" y="34"/>
      <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification" from_port="output" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Generate Data by User Specification (2)" from_port="output" to_op="Append" to_port="example set 2"/>
      <connect from_op="Append" from_port="merged set" to_port="out 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_in 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_out 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_out 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
    <description align="center" color="red" colored="true" width="126">Create sample data</description>
  </operator>
  <operator activated="true" class="split" compatibility="9.0.000-BETA" expanded="true" height="82" name="Split" width="90" x="313" y="34">
    <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="single"/>
    <parameter key="attribute" value="Name"/>
    <parameter key="split_pattern" value="\s"/>
  </operator>
  <operator activated="true" class="rename" compatibility="9.0.000-BETA" expanded="true" height="82" name="Rename" width="90" x="514" y="34">
    <parameter key="old_name" value="Name_1"/>
    <parameter key="new_name" value="Name"/>
    <list key="rename_additional_attributes">
      <parameter key="Name_2" value="New Number"/>
    </list>
    <description align="center" color="purple" colored="true" width="126">Change the names of the two split attributes</description>
  </operator>
  <operator activated="true" class="parse_numbers" compatibility="9.0.000-BETA" expanded="true" height="82" name="Parse Numbers" width="90" x="648" y="34">
    <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="single"/>
    <parameter key="attribute" value="New Number"/>
    <description align="center" color="purple" colored="true" width="126">Name was a string before, so we have to parse the &amp;quot;New Number&amp;quot; column</description>
  </operator>
  <operator activated="true" class="generate_attributes" compatibility="9.0.000-BETA" expanded="true" height="82" name="Generate Attributes" width="90" x="782" y="34">
    <list key="function_descriptions">
      <parameter key="New Number" value="if([New Number]==MISSING_NUMERIC, Number,[New Number])"/>
    </list>
  </operator>
  <connect from_op="Subprocess" from_port="out 1" to_op="Split" to_port="example set input"/>
  <connect from_op="Split" from_port="example set output" to_op="Rename" to_port="example set input"/>
  <connect from_op="Rename" from_port="example set output" to_op="Parse Numbers" to_port="example set input"/>
  <connect from_op="Parse Numbers" from_port="example set output" to_op="Generate Attributes" to_port="example set input"/>
  <connect from_op="Generate Attributes" from_port="example set output" to_port="result 1"/>
  <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
  <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
  <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
  <description align="center" color="yellow" colored="false" height="107" resized="false" width="180" x="277" y="119">Split the &amp;quot;Name&amp;quot; column (called Attribute in RapidMiner) along the blank (whitespace symbol \s)</description>
  <description align="center" color="green" colored="true" height="149" resized="true" width="169" x="764" y="125">Replace the missing values in &amp;quot;New Number&amp;quot; (where the Name didn't have a number) with the value of the Number column</description>
</process>
</operator>
</process>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot.

Comment: Great to hear. Could you please accept my answer, so the topic is closed?